# How to use extracted value in cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract information from Cell `B5` with the row information of Cell `C8`.
The result of Cell `C11` should be `3`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) formula

```
=INDIRECT("B"&C8)
```